# Exclude Files/Folder during TF get using command line

Tags: tfs

I have below mapped folder in local with TFS version control.

TFS version control folder ==> $/A/B/C
Local mapped folder ==> D:\MyFolder

Now from the command prompt, Getting all the latest files using below command

```
tf get D:\MyFolder /recursive /noprompt
```

Is there any way to exclude certain files/Folders while getting from TFS using the command line?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t ignore/exclude parameter in the `tf get` command line, but you can use specify the file/folder you want instead to use just `get`, for example `tf get 314.cs`.

In addition, you can cloak the files from the workspace: `tf workfold /cloak (Team Foundation source control serverfolder|localfolder) [/workspace: workspacename] [/s:servername]`.

Another option - to ignore certain files you can add `.tfignore` file to the repository.